# User is not authenticated after migration to .NET 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-8.0

I have migrated my API from .NET 5 to .NET 8. My issue is `HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated = false` even after I am passing a JwtToken in the header.

Here is my JWT configuration in the `StartUp.cs` (this code was working just fine in .NET 5):

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions =>
{
    jwtBearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    jwtBearerOptions.SaveToken = true;
    jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateActor = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
        ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Audience,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Key))
    };
    jwtBearerOptions.EventsType = typeof(JwtTokenValidatedEvent);
});
```

Here I have used `EventsTypes` where I am doing alteration in the `Claim` object. See these screenshots for illustration:

[image]

[image]

**EDITED (Code to Generate JWT Token)**

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new();
byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.Key);
List<Claim> claims = new()
{
    new Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId.ToString()),
    new Claim("companyid", Convert.ToString(user.CompanyId)),
    new Claim("usertypeid", Convert.ToString(user.UserTypeId)),
    new Claim("companyfacilityid", Convert.ToString(user.CompanyFacilityId)),
    new Claim("timezone", preferedTimeZone)
};

claims.AddRange(roles.Select(r => new Claim(Library.Common.UserRoleClaim, r)).ToList());

SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new()
{
    Audience = _jwtSettings.Audience,
    Issuer = _jwtSettings.Issuer,
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_jwtSettings.JWTTokenValidityMinutes),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Comment: You have to give future time limit at this line to keep the token valid ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0),

Comment: Tried but didn't work. Also, this code is working fine in .Net 5.

Comment: Could you add the login implementation for your question, the code snip where you add the user claims and SecurityTokenDescriptor & JwtSecurityTokenHandler that generates the token to the user

Comment: I added JWT token generation code in the main question

Comment: I think there is a difference between these two lines and you should unify using UTF8              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Key))<<<<==your code in service configuration          and  this line byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.Key); in token generation

Comment: Can you double check the value loaded for `_jwtSettings.JWTTokenValidityMinutes`?

Comment: What if remove the validation options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think .Net 8 is validating Claims in JWT Token differently. I tried

```
List<Claim> claims = new()
{
   
    new Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId.ToString()),
};
```

to

```
 List<Claim> claims = new()
 {
     new Claim(System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserId.ToString()),
    new Claim(System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.UserId.ToString())
}
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a Claim mapping issue,

try
[Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.jsonwebtokenhandler?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest) instead of

[System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.jsonwebtokenhandler?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest)

Also,try

```
new Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserId.ToString())
```

It failed to map claims in your jwt token to C# ClaimTypes due to the incorrect handler

also mkae sure you haven't disable the mapping :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(
    op =>
{
    // It,would be ture by default,don't set it to flase
    op.MapInboundClaims = false;
    // check the handler when you debug
   var tokenhandler = op.TokenHandlers;
    
});
```

Comment: No, I didn't disable mapping. Issue is related to claim mapping only. After changing "System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier" to "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub" and "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email" it worked. Here both these claims are required. One of them alone doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but have you tried explicitly setting the default scheme?, i.e.:

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

According to the docs, the default scheme will be set **if a single scheme is used**.  If multiple schemes are registered and the default scheme isn't specified, a scheme must be specified.

I had a similar issue using .Net 7.0 and explicitly setting the DefaultScheme worked.

Comment: Yes, I already added DefaultScheme but it didn't work.